# How to see value of the constant hovering on it somewhere in the code? [Pycharm IDE]

Tags: python, pycharm, keyboard-shortcuts

I've declared variable as a constant in the module beginning and some hundreds lines below I want to see it's value.

I know that it's possible to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and LMB to jump directly to declaration, but it's so distracting!

When I move mouse over variable's occurence with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> btn pressed I get only name and inferred type. I believe there is some way to see the value too.

Comment: "I believe there is some way to see the value too." What makes you think so? You can, however, see the value of any variable while hovering in debug mode in run time though.

Comment: @DeepSpace Two facts make me to believe so: 1. inferred type which is shown on the tooltip reflects constant's type, so I thought that I just don't press enough buttons to finish shortcuts combo 2. cool debugger's feature exists, I love it too, so why not to be the same thing for development mode? That's why I'm asking here.

Comment: There is no such functionality in PyCharm. Feel free to file an issue in bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found keyboard combination suitable for my needs.

Click on the variable somewhere in the code and use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to see constant's [definition](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-definition.html) with all its values included. Especially useful if this const was imported from other module so you don't have to jump to the declaration source.

On Mac OS it is <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

While you run your code in debugging mode use inline debugging functionality. This should lets you view the value of variables used in your source code right next to their usage, without having to switch to the Variables pane of the Debug tool window.
Enabling inline debugging

To enable it in Debug tool window toolbar click the **Settings icon** -> select the **Show Values** Inline option from the popup menu.

And then go to **Data Views** page in **Setting/Preferences** dialog select check box **Show values inline**.

Comment: Hi, that's not my downvote :) I've already had these settings turned on by default before. I'm asking about editor's feature, not debugger's one.

Comment: Would be nice to mention that those settings were turned on